# Program that can automatically perform an action whenever a given window appear on my screen

Tags: window-manager, productivity

I'm looking for a program that can automatically perform an action whenever a given window appear on my screen.

Example 1: on  Filezilla I keep having this window whenever I connected to an FTP server:

[image]

[Filezilla has no option](https://superuser.com/q/759932/116475) to avoid displaying this window. I would like to have a program that detects the appearance of the window and in this case just click on OK or press enter.

I would like to be able to configure which windows I want to detect as well as the actions that need to be perform.

Example 2:

I keep having this error message on Adobe Acrobat Pro, I would like the program to click on OK for me:

[image]

Ideally, I should be able to define the degree of similarity between the actual window that appears and window I configure to be detected. For instance PuTTY displays the following error message whenever I SSH into a new server:

[image]

(My use case so that you don't freak out: private network with no access to Internet, nobody else can have physically or remotely access to the machines except me. Server's host keys keep changing as I am experimenting with OpenStack.)

In this case the program should automatically click on Yes or press enter, but the server's key fingerprint is always different, so the program should have a flexible image recognition (e.g. like Sikuli does).

I am looking for a solution for all the OS I use, namely Windows, Ubuntu, Mac OS X and Android.

Comment: [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) might help you, but you'll need to write a script and I don't know if it's going to react fast enough to make a difference unless you can take a performance hit.

Comment: I think there's a good reason you might not want to script out PuTTY security alert. It's a security alert for a good reason.

Comment: @LieRyan No worries thanks for the warning but I take care of myself :)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: Scripting away that dialog box means you're disabling one of Putty's security protections, and it's a vulnerability that people have leveraged in the past.  Mind you, if you're unwilling to ever click cancel, the protection does nothing.  But such a strategy does not constitute taking care of yourself.  In other words, I disagree with your assertion that you're taking care of yourself.

Comment: @Brian OK my use case: private network with no access to Internet, nobody else can have physically or remotely access to the machines except me. Server's host keys keep changing as I am experimenting with OpenStack.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a simple scripting language.  [Autoit](http://autoitscript.com/) has the ability to wait for a given window to appear before proceeding with the script.  The *WinWait()* function will do this for you.

You will of course have to write the script but it is pretty simple.

When the script, which can be compiled, is in a wait state, it uses very little resource.